# Need help to catch AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax

I wrote the following code in my `home.php`.The `login()` function is called by clicking on submit button.

```
 function login()
  {
    try{
      xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
      try{
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e2){
      try{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch(e3){

      alert('Sorry ! AJAX not supported');
    }
    }
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4&&xmlHttp.status==200){
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('POST','ajax_call.php',true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    xmlHttp.send(document.getElementById('username').value,document.getElementById('password').value);
  }
  </script>
```

My ajax_call.php script is simply

```
<?
echo 'hello';
?>
```

I am not getting the alert `Hello`.Why?

[I tried to alert `readyState` and `status`

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      alert(xmlHttp.readyState+" "+xmlHttp.status);
      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4&&xmlHttp.status==200){
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    }
```

and got following in sequence

```
1 0
2 200
3 200
4 200
hello
1 0
hello
```

Comment: try removing the arguments from xmlHttp.send()

Comment: @Ankit:Tried but didn't help

Comment: So uhm... Doesn't that mean that your "Hello" does show up? This is what should happen, every time something changes in the request you get an update, it goes from 1 200 (send, no statuscode) to 2 200 (recieved, status OK) to eventually 4 200 (Ready with request, status OK) and after that you see the "Hello" you want... Right?

Comment: @CerylWiltink:But the browser is not showing Hello.Neither chrome nor firefox.

Comment: Hmm weird, I just copied your code exactly and only changed the php script location to a php file i made to echo 'hello' too. I get the alert just fine... Can you explain what exactly is not happening? Is there an alert-popup but no content? Or no alert at all maybe?

Comment: is there any reason why you need to do this by hand? you're going to have to do a lot of other 'stuff' if you want to keep your site cross-browser compatible... I'd use a js framework like jquery to get your ajax stuff working.... Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @CerylWiltink:I am not getting any alert box at all.I am using Linux for development.It sometimes create wierd problems ,maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
login()
      {
        try{
          xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
          try{
          xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e2){
          try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }catch(e3){

          alert('Sorry ! AJAX not supported');Or
        }
        }
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if(xmlHttp.readyState==4&&xmlHttp.status==200){
            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
          }
        }
        xmlHttp.open('POST','ajax_call.php',true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");/* Anil Remove ;*/
        xmlHttp.send('username'.value,'password'.value);/* try static username and password*/
      }
      </script>[ajax call][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line should just be

```
xmlHttp.send();
```

But it looks like you want to do some authentication... If it is basic authentication the values should go in a header, or if it is some kid of server authentication it depends on your implementation... Can you explain why you had the username/password in your xmlHttp.send() call?

Comment: Here is an example of how to add the basic authentication header btw: http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html I've used this tutorial before and got it to work...

Comment: :I am  picking the values from login form and then logging the user using AJAX.But here I put 'hello' just to test it.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea :

- I think you must **open** your xmlHttp **before** onreadystatechange !

The third parameter of .open tells xmlHttp to fire onreadystatechange 
(that's why it is set to true)

however, if that is not the bug:

- did you try **this.responseText** ?